# Setting formBorderStyle to None fails with error FormBorderStyle is used as a variable

Tags: c#, winforms, fullscreen

```
System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Maximized;
```

I am trying to set the `FormBorderStyle` to None (to get fullscreen) but I  I always get an error that the

> FormBorderStyle is used as a variable.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this line of code that you have. This line works because it is saying that the `WindowState` is assigned the value on the right.

```
WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Maximized;
```

Then you have this line of code:

```
System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
```

That is similar to doing something like this:

```
int = int; // will not work
```

Both on the left and right side you have a type. You need to change it to this:

```
FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
```

Now you are saying that `FormBorderStyle` of current window is the value on the right.

**EDIT**

In WPF you will do it like this:

```
this.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
```

Comment: If I do that C# says that FormBorderStyle does not even exists in this content

Comment: At the beginning I tried it global. It didn't work so know I wrote it in my methods. Still does not go.

Comment: That is not possible. If you write that code in your form load or in the constructor it will work. You can write it anywhere in your form but it makes sense to do it in the constructor or the load method.

Comment: I think to problem is that I use a MainWindow Class. Could it be the bug?

Comment: No it is not a bug. Are you sure you are using windows forms?

Comment: Do you mean System.Window.Forms? Yes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133723/discussion-between-codingyoshi-and-tizaljubavnisirodjena).

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to set type to one of its possible values, so it's not going to work.

You need to assign the [`Form.FormBorderStyle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formborderstyle(v=vs.110).aspx) property on the instance of that form in some event handler or inside its constructor.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    }
    ...
```

Also you can probably set this property through the [designer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ew6tzdt(v=vs.100).aspx) if your application never has to have another border style.

Comment: I get this error now: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression StateError CS1061 'MainWindow' does not contain a definition for 'System' and no extension method 'System' accepting a first argument of type 'MainWindow' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @TiZaLjubavNisiRodjena  Not sure how you got that error. I have missed the semicolon at the end of the line - perhaps that was the reason? Otherwise you should provide the code for that method.